# Get Progress in Python file Upload to Azure

Tags: python, azure, filestream

i'm uploading files to azure like so:

```
with open(tempfile, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data, blob_type='BlockBlob',  length=None, metadata=None)
```

how can i get a progress indication?
when i try uploading as stream, it only uploads one chunk.

i'm sure i'm doing something wrong, but can't find info.

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the Azure library doesn't include a callback function to monitor progress.

Fortunately, you can add a wrapper around Python's file object which can call a callback everytime there's a read.

Try this:

```
import os
from io import BufferedReader, FileIO


class ProgressFile(BufferedReader):
    # For binary opening only

    def __init__(self, filename, read_callback):
        f = FileIO(file=filename, mode='r')
        self._read_callback = read_callback
        super().__init__(raw=f)

        # I prefer Pathlib but this should still support 2.x
        self.length = os.stat(filename).st_size

    def read(self, size=None):
        calc_sz = size
        if not calc_sz:
            calc_sz = self.length - self.tell()
        self._read_callback(position=self.tell(), read_size=calc_sz, total=self.length)
        return super(ProgressFile, self).read(size)



def my_callback(position, read_size, total):
    # Write your own callback. You could convert the absolute values to percentages
    
    # Using .format rather than f'' for compatibility
    print("position: {position}, read_size: {read_size}, total: {total}".format(position=position,
                                                                                read_size=read_size,
                                                                                total=total))


myfile = ProgressFile(filename='mybigfile.txt', read_callback=my_callback)
```

Then you would do

```
blob_client.upload_blob(myfile, blob_type='BlockBlob',  length=None, metadata=None)

myfile.close()
```

**Edit:**
It looks like TQDM (progress monitor) has a neat wrapper: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#hooks-and-callbacks.
The bonus there is that you get easy access to a pretty progress bar.

Comment: @Benny I just added details of TQDM, which has a similar solution with the added benefit of a progress bar.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I ended up using the `tqdm` wrapper that Alastair mentioned above

```
  from tqdm import tqdm

  size = os.stat(fname).st_size
  with tqdm.wrapattr(open(fname, 'rb'), "read", total=size) as data:
     blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

Works perfectly, shows time estimate, progress bar, human readable file sizes and transfer speeds.

Comment: This worked for me, nice solution. Just for clarification, you can also add: `from tqdm import tqdm`