# Django - upload a file to the cloud (Azure blob storage) with progress bar

Tags: python, django, ajax, azure, progress-bar

I'm following [this](https://anshu-dev.medium.com/file-upload-progress-bar-using-django-and-ajax-ba4eb7482d9c) tutorial to add a progress bar when I'm uploading a file in Django, using ajax.
When I'm uploading the file to a folder using the `upload_to` option everything works fine.
But when I'm uploading the file to Azure using the `storage` option - It doesn't work.
i.e. when this is my model:

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file=models.FileField(upload_to='files/media/pre')
```

It works perfect, but when this is my model:

```
from myAzure import AzureMediaStorage as AMS
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = models.FileField(storage=AMS)
```

It gets stuck and not progressing.
(AMS is defined in myAzure.py by):

```
from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage

class AzureMediaStorage(AzureStorage):
    account_name = '<myAccountName>'
    account_key = '<myAccountKey>'
    azure_container = 'media'
    expiration_secs = None
```

How can I make it work?

EDIT:
If it was not clear:

- my problem is not to upload to Azure, but to show progress bar.
- From security reasons I do not want to upload the file from the browser and to use CORS and SAS but from my backend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Azure upload file to blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54729137/django-azure-upload-file-to-blob-storage)

Comment: [Upload File with Progress from Browser to Azure Blob Storage](https://edi.wang/post/2021/7/7/upload-file-with-progress-from-browser-to-azure-blob-storage)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT no. My problem is not to upload, but to show progress bar when I'm uploading. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

When one is uploading a file to a specific place, in order to track the current state of the upload either one adds a wrapper around the Python object or the place where one is uploading to provides a callback for monitoring.

Since the Azure library doesn't provide that callback, one can create a wrapper for the object or use an already existing one.

There's a library suggested by [Alastair McCormack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62792935/7109869) named [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#hooks-and-callbacks) with such wrapper that one can use.

As [George John shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71345630/7109869), one can do something like this

```
size = os.stat(fname).st_size
with tqdm.wrapattr(open(fname, 'rb'), "read", total=size) as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I saw this too, but I didn't figure out how to integrate this when I'm creating an instance of UploadFile in the view (and show the progress in the template to the client)?

Comment: Where are you grabbing `from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage` from?

It appears that with that you are trying to [use a custom storage class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-file-storage/) but using django-storages[azure]. Is that so?

Comment: Also, did you define `AZURE_LOCATION`? [That problem happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54745018/7109869)

Comment: @BinyaminEven just raising attention to my previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to try the work-around of storing file locally and then upload to Azure.

Not sure if it will work but at least you may give it a try and tell if helps:

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/media/pre', null=True, blank=False)
    remote_file = models.FileField(storage=AMS, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.file:
            self.remote_file = self.file
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # in theory - this should trigger upload of remote_file
            self.file = None 
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```